# forgot or have forgotten my id card

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

Today, I came to office without Id card and hence took temporary staff pass. I just need to inform my HR on this by email which sentence I should use out of these two.

> I **have forgotten** my id card today.

or

> I **forgot** my id card today.

Answer (score 2):

The first version is *more clear* since it shows that you still/currently **have** the situation of your ID card being not available (= you have it forgotten somewhere). The version with Past Indefinite just describes past events: who knows, maybe you've already solved that problem? However, in the given context (asking for a temporary pass) both versions work.